# What is the difference between algebra and $\sigma$-algebra generated in a finite space?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

For a finite set $\Omega$ with (obviously finite) class $C$.
Does the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$ $=$ the algebra generated by $C$?

I think it does. But I'm not sure I understand if there is a difference between 
union and countable union for finite classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are the same -- there are only finitely many possible unions you can take, so allowing for countable unions doesn't gain you anything.